# Multiple web docker containers on a host

Tags: apache, docker, nginx, containers

What is the best practice concerning multiple web containers running on a single host.

How would I assign these subdomains 
`subdomain1.mydomain.com to container1` and 
`subdomain2.mydomain.com to container2` 
when both containers run on `host1` with `ports 50000 and 50001`?

How would this configuration work if I wanted to assign paths to both containers e.g.: `mydomain.com/pathnameleadingtocontainer1` , `mydomain.com/pathnameleadingtocontainer2` again with both containers running on `host1` with ports `50000 and 50001`?

Comment: Set up apache or nginx as a web proxy?

Comment: @tier1 could you explain?

Comment: Scenario:  You have 2 docker containers running on 1 machine, mapped to host port 50000 and 50001.  So you would install and run an apache server directly on the host machine.  By configuring apache as a proxy, you can redirect all incoming traffic based on the domain .  When a request of subdomain1.mydomain.com hits apache, it will redirect the traffic to localhost:50000 for example.

Comment: @tier1 so the apache on host machine redirects to the apache port 50000 of that container? did I understand that correctly?